# Merge Sorted Array leetcode

Tags: javascript, merge

```
var merge = function(nums1, m, nums2, n) {

    //contcating two array
     let array = nums2.concat(nums1)
    // sort the array
     array.sort((a,b) => a-b)
     // remove element > m+n length
 return array.slice(m+n-n)
};
```

This ^ function is returning ->  [1,2,3,0,0,0]
if i'm applying console then answer is same as expected   -> [1,2,2,3,5,6]

Why is this happening ?

Comment: What's the input? `num1`, `m`, `num2` and `n`?

Comment: nums1 ->[1,2,3,0,0,0] 
nums2 ->[2,5,6]
n , m -> 3

Comment: So `m` and `n` are both 3? The last line you are removing index 3+3-3 ...so `slice(3)` will return an array without the first 3 numbers...why? and why not just `m` if `n-n`?

Comment: `m + n - n` = m !?  do you mean  `array.slice(m+n,n)`

Comment: with 2 arrays : `[1,2,3.0,0,0]` and `[2,5,6]` . result is `[1,2,2,3,5,6]`, must be `array.slice(3)` or `array.slice(3, array.length)`

Answer (score 4):

`Remove` slice function from the end of the function.
`slice(m+n-n)` slices your sorted array and returns array from index m+1 to the last index.

```js
var merge = function(nums1, m, nums2, n) {

    //contcating two array
     let array = nums2.concat(nums1)
    // sort the array
     array.sort((a,b) => a-b)
     // remove element > m+n length
 return array.slice(m+n-n);
};

console.log(merge([2,4,8,9],4,[0,4,6,9],4));
```

You can use the following function to merge and then sort the two arrays.
Time complexity of this approach is `O(nlogn)`

```js
function merge(arr1,arr2){
  return [...arr1,...arr2].sort();
}

console.log(merge([4,8,6],[1,3,9,10]));
```

The second approach runs in `O(n)` time.

```js
 function merge(arr1,m,arr2,n){
          let result = [];
          let i=0 , j = 0 ;
          while(i<m && j<n){
            if(arr1[i]<arr2[j]){
              result.push(arr1[i]);
              i++;
            }else{
              result.push(arr2[j]);
              j++;
            }
          }
          while(i<m){
            result.push(arr1[i]);
            i++;
          }
          while(j<n){
            result.push(arr2[j]);
            j++;
          }
          return result;
     }

        console.log(merge([4,5,6],3,[1,3,8,10],4));
```

Comment: Hey, If this solution helped. Accept the solution as it would help others find the correct solution quick. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Hritik Sharma for response ,but  I want to know what's wrong in my code.

Comment: Why do you need slice function at the end ?

Comment: Remove that slice function that would solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

It is mentioned that **Do not return anything, modify nums1 in-place instead.**, So the output is your nums1 array and not array which you have created.

Note: To resolve this issue you can modify the nums1 array, below is the sample code:

```
var merge = function(nums1, m, nums2, n) {
   const index = nums1.length - n;
    for(let i=index;i < nums1.length;i++) {
        nums1[i] = nums2[i-index];
    }
    nums1.sort((a,b)=> a-b);
    
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not see any problem with your code and it works, I just added another code. I think the problem with your `console.log`.

```js
var merge = function(nums1, m, nums2, n) {

    //contcating two array
     let array = nums2.concat(nums1)
    // sort the array
     array.sort((a,b) => a-b)
     // remove element > m+n length
 return array.slice(m+n-n)
};

console.log(merge([1,2,3,0,0,0],3,[2,5,6],3));
```

```js
var merge = function(nums1, m, nums2, n) {
    return    nums1.slice(0, m)
    .concat(nums2.slice(0, n))
    .sort((i, j) => i - j);
       
       
    };

  console.log(  merge([1,2,3,0,0,0],3,[2,5,6],3))
```

Answer (score 0):

By using simple for loop

```js
let arr1 = [10, 20, 30, 45, 50]

let arr2 = [15, 25, 26, 35]

const mergeArray = (arr1, arr2) => {

  let arr3 = []
  let i = 0;
  let j = 0;

  for (let n = 0; n < arr1.length + arr2.length; n++) {
    if (arr1[i] <= arr2[j] || arr2.length < j + 1) {
      arr3.push(arr1[i])
      i++
    } else {
      arr3.push(arr2[j])
      j++
    }
  }
  return arr3
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(mergeArray(arr1, arr2)))
```